# relation of particular model with controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a controller named CardsController and a model name Card.I want to know that when i use Card::all() in controller how it relates to Cards db table.not other table.Iam  new  to laravel .can someone suggest me?

```
 cntroller: 

        <?php

            namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\card;
    class CardsController extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function index()
        {
            # code...
            // $cards = DB::table('cards')->get();
            $cards= card::all();
            return view('cards.index',compact('cards'));
        }

         public function show($id)
         {
            $cards = card::find($id);
            return view('cards.show',compact('cards'));
         }
    }

Model:


    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class card extends Model
    {
        //
    }

miggrations table:

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCardsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cards');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records in the flights table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions